# Problem with \frac macro

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I am using this code for a mathematics problem. The code works but the lower fraction looks really dull, the parenthesis is doing something it isn't supposed to. What I can do about this?

```
\begin{align}
D &= \sum_{i}^{k}\frac{n_i}{\frac{A}({\Delta\sigma_i})^m} \nonumber \\
D &= \sum_{i}^{k}\frac{n_i}{\frac{A}({r_i*\Delta\sigma_{max}})^m} \nonumber \\
D &= \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{max})^m}{A} \sum_{i}^{k}\frac{n_i}{(r_i)^m} \nonumber \\
D &= \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{max})^m}{A} * C \label{eq:constant}
\end{align}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  If you indent your code  4 spaces, it shows as code.  Alternately, highlight it and click on the `{}` icon at the top of the editing box.

Comment: In your first two equations, it is not clear whether you want the whole denominator to have the exponent or only the denominator of the denominator.

Comment: The problem is `{\frac{A}({\Delta\sigma_i})^m}`. The correct syntax for `\frac` is `\frac{above}{below}`. In your code `(` is the denominator, which is not what you want ;)

Comment: Please include a complete minimum working example. (Your LaTeX is non-standard as it relies on `amsmath`.)

Comment: Remember to accept the answer you find most useful (if, indeed, any of them are useful to you).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative presentation to avoid fractions within fractions.  EDITED to reflect clarified intent of the OP in the comment section.

Also, use `\max` instead of `max`, since it is a function.

REEDITED to take Mico's suggestion of using `\cdot` rather than the `*`.  That is, perhaps, assuming something on the intent of the OP, but it seems a reasonable assumption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
D &= \sum_{i}^{k}n_i\cdot\frac{({\Delta\sigma_i})^m}{A}\nonumber \\
D &= \sum_{i}^{k}n_i\cdot\frac{({r_i\cdot\Delta\sigma_{\max}})^m}{A} \nonumber \\
D &= \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{\max})^m}{A} \sum_{i}^{k}\frac{n_i}{(r_i)^m} \nonumber \\
D &= \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{\max})^m}{A}\cdot C \label{eq:constant}
\end{align}
Here is what you had:
\begin{align}
D &= \sum_{i}^{k}\frac{n_i}{\frac{A}({\Delta\sigma_i})^m} \nonumber \\
D &= \sum_{i}^{k}\frac{n_i}{\frac{A}({r_i*\Delta\sigma_{max}})^m} \nonumber \\
D &= \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{max})^m}{A} \sum_{i}^{k}\frac{n_i}{(r_i)^m} \nonumber \\
D &= \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{max})^m}{A} * C \label{eq:constant}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, it was the first version i would like to have.

Comment: @user70916 EDITED to reflect your intent.

Comment: I'd be tempted either to get rid of the asterisks entirely or to replace them `\cdot`.

Comment: @Mico  You are right.  I think I had originally left them there so as to not assume something on the part of the OP.  But the intent seems reasonably clear.

Comment: @Mico Unless it's a specific type of product (scalar, vector, tensor), I would omit the multiplication symbols altogether, they are superfluous. In some places, a thin space should be then added, basically anywhere before `\Delta`.

Comment: @yo' - I think we're in agreement that *not* using asterisks is the way to go, right?

Comment: @Mico Yes. I would just _not_ offer `\cdot` as an alternative :)

Comment: @yo' - For a good example of when to use thinspace instead of any kind of multiplication symbol, see the posting http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239942/5001...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Excuse me very much. :-( I have not seen the original question. I will delete all.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected the placement of the parenthesis in your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
D &= \sum_{i}^{k}\frac{n_i}{\frac{A}{(\Delta\sigma_i)^m}} \nonumber \\
D &= \sum_{i}^{k}\frac{n_i}{\frac{A}{(r_i*\Delta\sigma_{max})^m}} \nonumber \\
D &= \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{max})^m}{A} \sum_{i}^{k}\frac{n_i}{(r_i)^m} \nonumber \\
D &= \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{max})^m}{A} * C \label{eq:constant}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent Either
\begin{align}
\label{eq:constant:A}
D &= \sum_{i = \cdots}^{k} \frac{n_{i} \cdot (\Delta\sigma_{i})^{m}}{A} \nonumber \\
  &= \sum_{i = \cdots}^{k} \frac{n_{i} \cdot (r_{i} \cdot \Delta\sigma_{\max})^{m}}{A} \nonumber \\
  &= \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{\max})^{m}}{A} \cdot \sum_{i = \cdots}^{k}\frac{n_{i}}{{r_{i}}^{m}} \nonumber \\
  &= \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{\max})^{m}}{A} \cdot C
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\label{eq:constant:B}
D &= \sum_{i = \cdots}^{k} \frac{n_{i}(\Delta\sigma_{i})^{m}}{A} \nonumber \\
  &= \sum_{i = \cdots}^{k} \frac{n_{i}(r_{i}\Delta\sigma_{\max})^{m}}{A} \nonumber \\
  &= \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{\max})^{m}}{A}\sum_{i = \cdots}^{k}\frac{n_{i}}{{r_{i}}^{m}} \nonumber \\
  &= \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{\max})^{m}}{A}C
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

If the margins in your document are a bit smaller, you can consider doing the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent Another solutiuon using the \texttt{geometry} package to avoid the formulae going into the margin:
\begin{align}
\label{eq:constant:A}
D &= \sum_{i = \cdots}^{k} \frac{n_{i} \cdot (\Delta\sigma_{i})^{m}}{A}
   = \sum_{i = \cdots}^{k} \frac{n_{i} \cdot (r_{i} \cdot \Delta\sigma_{\max})^{m}}{A}
   = \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{\max})^{m}}{A} \cdot \sum_{i = \cdots}^{k}\frac{n_{i}}{{r_{i}}^{m}}
   = \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{\max})^{m}}{A} \cdot C
\intertext{or}
\label{eq:constant:B}
D &= \sum_{i = \cdots}^{k} \frac{n_{i}(\Delta\sigma_{i})^{m}}{A}
   = \sum_{i = \cdots}^{k} \frac{n_{i}(r_{i}\Delta\sigma_{\max})^{m}}{A}
   = \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{\max})^{m}}{A}\sum_{i = \cdots}^{k}\frac{n_{i}}{{r_{i}}^{m}}
   = \frac{(\Delta\sigma_{\max})^{m}}{A}C
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Notes:

- There is only one `D` in each approach.
- There is no fraction within a fraction in either approach.
- In the solution at the top, the `*`s are replaced by `\cdot`s.
- In the solution at the bottom, all the `\cdot`s are removed.

P.S. Rememeber to replace the `\cdots`.